# How to Perform Inplace Animations in React Three Fiber

Tags: animation, three.js, 3d, game-development, react-three-fiber

I imported a 3D model from Mixamo with some animations and was wondering how to perform does animations in place?
The GLTF file I created from npx gltfjsx:

```
  const { nodes, materials, animations } = useGLTF("/Mannequin.glb");
  const { actions } = useAnimations(animations, heroRef);

  return (
    <>
      <group ref={heroRef} dispose={null}>
        <group rotation={[Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} scale={0.01}>
          <primitive object={nodes.mixamorig1Hips} />
          <skinnedMesh
            geometry={nodes.Ch36.geometry}
            material={materials.Ch36_Body}
            skeleton={nodes.Ch36.skeleton}
          />
        </group>

        {/* <gridHelper args={[25, 25]}/> */}
      </group>
    </>
  );
}

useGLTF.preload("/Mannequin.glb");
```

For example, I would like the model to perform the run animation without changing locations (running on the spot) so that if I can perform user controls that translate the model and with the animation looping, it would look like they were actually running.

Are there any ways to do this? I have searched and could not find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    useEffect(() => {
    console.log(actions) // find out the name of your action
    actions.someAction.play()
    });
```

This will make the animation play in place, if it was exported like that from mixamo, there is a setting.

Then you can put a  around your mesh and make it move based on your control

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't use `console.log(actions)` to see available actions as they were undefined and I had `{}` in console. My code **was**:

```
const { actions } = useAnimations(animations, group);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(actions);
}, [actions]);
```

So I digged inside into `useAnimations` source code and saw two things:

1. actions object is not being updated, only it's properties, so `useEffect` doesn't trigger when ref updates.
2. if `ref.current` is undefined (as for first render) properties are undefined. that's why I saw `{}` in console.

So I **changed** my code **to**:

```
const { actions } = useAnimations(animations, group);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(Object.keys(actions));
}, [actions]);
```

That's how I saw that my animation names were: `['Female_Idle', 'Female_Talk']`

**And**

```
const { actions } = useAnimations(animations, group);
const action = actions['Female_Idle'];

useEffect(() => {
  if (action) action.play();
}, [action]);
```

In order to play action, when ref updates. That did the trick.